# Ionic / Angular JS calling the next page by passing a value into a funciton

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to figure out how to submit ng-click="doSomething()" with some parameter.  For example - I have a controller and a view that generates a list of countries has two fields - countryname and id.   If I do ng-repeat='item in countrydata'  i can get a values as {{ item.id }} and {{ item.countryname }}.  This will list all the country ids with their name.  Next I would like to tap on this list item and pass the value ng-click="getStates({{ item.id }})" to get a list of states for that country.  I have a controller setup called CountryController.  The init() function in it gets me the list of countries and their ids.  Then getstates() function is supposed to take the item.id and get me the list of states.  The restful apis i have developed work fine in Postman if I pass the country id to get states for that country.  But when i use the  View states  nothing happens. I have my templates and routes set up.  Both functions are part of the same controller and scope is also initialized as {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngClick has direct access to `$scope`, which means you can't pass interpolated expressions to it (i.e. `{{someExpression}}`), you can simply pass the object as-is:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in countrydata">
  <button ng-click="getStates(item.id)>Get States</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
app.controller('SomeController', function($scope){ 
   scope.getStates = function(id) {
       // do stuff with id
   }
})
```

Comment: Lux, thank you for your response.  For some reason i is still not working.  Below is my html file:

Comment: app hangs  Webservice is not slow.  html <ion-view ng-controller="CountryController"  title="Select Country">  <ion-content overflow-scroll=”true”><ion-list  ng-model="init()">
 <div ng-repeat="item in countrydata">
{{ item.id }}
{{ item.name }}
<button class="button" ng-click="getStaes(item.id)">view item</button>
  </div> </ion-list>
      </ion-content> </ion-view>$http.get('http://myapi').then(function(response) { 
$scope.countrydata = response.data;
          $scope.countrydata.id = response.data.id;
          $scope.countrydata.name = response.data.name;

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but does this meet your expectation? http://plnkr.co/edit/eNhv30FG3WdsSWTlMsNB?p=info Obviously the click function would do more (i.e. get the states), but is this functionally what you're trying to achieve? Click and get the item?

Comment: Ok did some debugging of my own code.  For some reason ng-repeat starts an infinite loop.  First I was suspecting that my webservice response was causing some issue.  But instead turns out it is ng-repeat  I tried the array below:  $scope.countrydata = [

                {id: 1, country: 'USA'},
                {id: 2, country: 'Canada'},
                {id: 3, country: 'Mexico'},
                {id: 4, country: 'France'}
                ];     My code is the same as of plunger.  The $http.get you see is original webservice call i am no longer making

Comment: The $scope.init() was causing the infinite loop. Thank you for your help.